# d3.js trouble parsing "MNaN,NaN"

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to draw a map with d3.js but I keep getting `Problem parsing d="MNaN,NaN"`

```
    <!-- language: lang-js -->
    var width=960, height=500;
    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);
    var q = 0;
    var sc = 3000;
    var d3line2 = d3.svg.line()
                    .x(function(d){q= 0.95105*sc*(d[0]+66.4262);  return q;})
                    .y(function(d){q= sc*(-1*d[1]+ 18.2336);  return q;})
                    .interpolate("linear"); 

    d3.json("/prCounties.json", function(d){

        for(var k = 0; k < d.features[0].length; k++){
            svg.append("path")
            .attr("d", d3line2(d.features[0][k].geometry.coordinates) )
            .attr("class", "stroke");
        }
    });
```

Here is the GeoJson file - it should be identical to what's on [GitHub](https://github.com/johan/world.geo.json/blob/master/countries/USA/PR/Adjuntas.geo.json).

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection", 
"properties": {"kind": "state", "state": "PR"}, 
"features": [[
    {"geometry": {"type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [[[[-66.7222, 18.2198], [-66.6838, 18.2034], [-66.6729, 18.1541], [-66.6948, 18.1322], [-66.7167, 18.1322], [-66.7331, 18.1103], [-66.7715, 18.1377], [-66.7989, 18.1322], [-66.8262, 18.1705], [-66.8153, 18.2308], [-66.7824, 18.2527]]]]}, 
"type": "Feature", "properties": {"kind": "county", "name": "Adjuntas", "state": "PR"}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be more than one issue (and a jsFiddle would help), but here's one:

The `d3.svg.line()` generator expects an array of points. You're giving it `[[[[-66.7222, 18.2198], [-66.6838, 18.2034]....`, which *is* an array of points, but it's further nested into two more levels of arrays. I guess that's because the `coordinates` property by spec can describe multiple segments (like multiple islands making up a single geo entity, or a "hole", like a lake within a boundary).

So in your case you need to give it `d.features[0][k].geometry.coordinates[0][0]`

Having said all that, and without knowing the purpose, notice that you'd be plotting longitude latitude pairs, not projected X,Y points. If the latter is what you're expecting, then you'll want to look into `d3.geo.path()`, which will allow you to specify a projection.

Comment: JsFiddle.  That's a good call.  It came out ok.  [map](https://a248.e.akamai.net/camo.github.com/521b09a4A0d52539fd2b83060503d96bada85d277/687474703a2f2f646c2e64726f70626f782e636f6d2f752f31373934393130302f70722e706e67)